# File content upload using JSON

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I am attempting to upload a file from the browser to a Spring 3.0 MVC application (hosted in Glassfish). The intent is to send the file content through a JSON request.

Attempting to read the file using JavaScript and then placing the file content in a JSON request does not seem advisable as the file content may be large and consume memory on the browser.

Next I attempted using the [mootools uploadManager](http://mootools.net/forge/p/uploadmanager). The documentation and demos deal only with a php server. There is de-coding of the file contents by the php script that handles the upload. So to use mootools uploadManager, I would have to simulate the de-coding (contained in the php script) in my Spring MVC controller. Since this isn't going to be straight forward, I am wondering if there are other elegant solutions to this issue (after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763787/how-to-upload-file-via-the-json-interface-in-rails) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301799/possible-to-upload-file-and-parse-the-json-result)).

TIA,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

I actually think it would be pretty straight forward to do it in the Spring controller...

1. simply treat it as any other [file upload](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart)
2. then read the file contents and run it through [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) (or the JSON lib of your choice)

[edit: deleted RestTemplate reference as it requires URI to json, not a file]

Comment: @nichdos, Thank you for the response. Apparently, XMLHttpRequest cannot send files (from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mootools-users/browse_thread/thread/2ab5c5a3754682ca?pli=1)). So, from what I understand, it skips all <input type="file"../> elements. So got to figure out another way to do this.

Comment: What about sending the JSON in a POST via AJAX. I know you said it might use up too much memory but the JSON would have to be pretty huge for this to be an issue (> 100 MB of JSON). I think you might be guilty of early optimisation (root of all...), try it and benchmark it before judging :-)